# Ambiguity in variadic function template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I recently started trying out various template tricks. In this case I tried to implement a class holding a sequence of numbers supplied by a variadic template utilizing a parameter pack.

However, I run into some problems that do **not** occur on the compiler I use (**Intel C++ 14**), but on others like **CLang** or **GCC**. I am therefore quite confused about which compiler is "more on point" in its interpretation of the standard.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template< size_t... Sequence >
class CSequence
{ 
    public:
        CSequence()
        {
            this->generate< Sequence... >();
            this->out();
        }

    private:
        // Recursion end
        template< size_t N >
        void generate(size_t sz)
        {
            // Create array
            this->m_Array = new size_t[sz+1];

            this->m_Len = sz+1;

            this->m_Array[sz] = N;
        }

        // Recursion segment
        template< size_t N, size_t... Ns >
        void generate(size_t sz)
        {
            generate<Ns...>(sz+1);

            this->m_Array[sz] = N;
        }

        // Recursion start
        template< size_t... Ns >
        void generate()
        {
            generate<Ns...>(0);
        }         

        void out()
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < this->m_Len; i++)
            {
                std::cout << this->m_Array[i] << " ";
            }

            std::cout << std::endl;
        }

    private:
        size_t*     m_Array;
        size_t      m_Len;
};

int main()
{
    CSequence< 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 > a;
   std::getchar();
}
```

This compiles fine on my end using **Intel C++ 14** and produces the result I would expect:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

But on the newest versions of both CLang and GCC it fails to compile:

- CLang [@ wandbox Online compiler](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/DHtgCQF7FSXXXT3u)
- GCC [@ wandbox Online compiler](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/i1o9Q4jugjGMEGQy)

Now, I can actually understand the reason for the failure: As parameter packs can contain zero elements, the exemplary call

```
generate< 8 >( size_t );
```

may be resolved both as

```
generate< N = 8, Ns = <> > ( size_t )
```

and as

```
generate< N = 8 > ( size_t )
```

thus resulting in an unresolvable ambiguity. But the fact that it compiles on my end and actually gives the expected result makes me wonder:

1. Which compiler is "right"? Obviously **Intel C++** makes some additional decisions compared to CLang or GCC. Is this "illegal" concerning the standard? Or are the GCC/CLang simply lacking?
2. Are there any ways to circumvent this behaviour?

Note that this piece of code is to be considered as some kind of experiment, so I'm happy with both alternative strategies and fixes for this particular piece of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't require a recursive implementation at all.

```
template< size_t... Ns >
void generate()
{
    m_Len = sizeof...(Ns);
    m_Array = new size_t[m_Len] { Ns... };
}
```

You can also dispense with the dynamic allocation and make `m_Array` an actual array, and initialize it with a NSDMI:

```
size_t m_Array[sizeof...(Sequence)] = {Sequence... };
```

Comment: Thank you. I marked this as the answer because it is actually a better solution, not just a fix.

Answer (score 3):

Clang and GCC are correct as parameter packs can contain zero elements and there is no partial ordering defined for this case, so the call is ambiguous.

The easiest way to fix this is to make the recursive case take an additional template argument. This way, the call is completely unambiguous:

```
// Recursion segment
template< size_t N1, size_t N2, size_t... Ns >
//              extra param ^^
void generate(size_t sz)
{
    generate<N2,Ns...>(sz+1);
    //add N2 ^^

    this->m_Array[sz] = N1;
}
```

Comment: ... the easiest way to fix this is to not use recursion at all.

Comment: @T.C. if you want to share a way without recursion feel free to post another answer. I mentioned that I am open to alternative solutions. Thanks.